# How could I emulate the 6502 JMP, branching, and sub-routine in C++?

Tags: function, branch, 6502

I have a program that is supposed to fully emulate a MOS Technologies 6502 processor. I have almost completely implemented the entire instruction set into c++ functions, including mathematical, bitwise functions. I even can emulate clock speed. The only instructions i have not successfully implemented are the JMP and all branching instructions, as well as subroutine instructions. This is because i do not know how to make a goto-like loop for C++. As my header is too large to put into a code block, i have linked it as the file "6502.h". Any step-by-step help would be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1j1lbKWU98iQ1dyVGNCVzRzdDA/view?usp=sharing [6502.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1j1lbKWU98iQ1dyVGNCVzRzdDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Some other tips: Look for deeper understanding of what conversions etc the compiler will do for you so you can avoid redundant code. Your bit7 function could simply be return ((x & 128)==128), since == yields a bool. Or return (x & 128) since that will get converted to a bool. Or return (x & (1 << 7)) since the magic number is more self-explanatory. Also try to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle by factoring out common code like "if(emulateClockSpeed)" etc. Anyway, have fun. Emulation is a good way to hone your skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of me wants to close this as off-topic - questions of the type 'finish my code for me' and 'why doesn't this code work' are undesirable on SO.

However, it's Friday afternoon, I should be writing some staff reviews, and this is a welcome distraction. I'm not going to give you code, but I will give you a couple of hints:

1. You don't have a PC (program counter) variable.
2. BxC, BxS, JSR, JMP, RTI, RTS and BRK all work by making changes to PC.

(by the way, you might want to look at the opcode descriptions for PHP/PLP a little more closely)

Comment: Thanks, I felt like i could almost get away with just making it so that the branching, subroutine and break just returned true or false values that the user could just do whatever with. I just thought that adding a program counter would be a little complex for my skill. I'll try to implement a PC and  fix the instructions. the PHP and PLP instructions i'm going to fix as well.

Comment: You're already managing SP on the PHx/PLx opcodes; manipulating PC is more of the same sort of thing, just a *little* more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code, to give an idea;

```
// Emulation loop
opcode = memory[pc++]
switch(opcode)
case JMP
  target = memory[pc] | memory[pc+1]<<8
  pc = target
case JSR
  target = memory[pc] | (memory[pc+1]<<8)
  stack[sp--] = pc<<8
  stack[sp--] = pc&0xff
  pc = target
case RTS
  pc = stack[sp+1] | (stack[sp+2]<<8)
  sp += 2
...
```